# Given $(I+BB^T)^{-1}$ find the scaled inverse $(I+BDB^T)^{-1}$ fast.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $(I_k+BB^T)^{-1}$ be given for $B\in \mathbb{R}^{k\times d}$ where $k\ll d$.

Find $(I_k+BDB^T)^{-1}$ when $D\in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is a diagonal matrix with $D_{ii}=1/(d_{ii}-\alpha)$ for $d_{ii},\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ so $D^{-1}$ exists.

You may also assume that $BB^T$ and its eigendecomposition $BB^T=U\Sigma U^T$ are given. The particular values of $k$ and $d$ in my problem are $k=64$ and $d=2048$.

Comment: This doesn't make use of the known inverse, but it is notable that both of these inverses can be computed via the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) using only a $d \times d$ inversion.

Comment: If $D$ has many entries equal to $1$, then $I + BDB^T$ can be thought of as a low-rank update to $I + BB^T$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated an error in the original question wrt shapes and added more information to the structure of $D$.

Comment: It seems that Woodbury tells me I can (ignoring a few terms) change $(I_k+BDB^T)^{-1}$ to $(D^{-1}+B^TB)^{-1}$, i.e., change the scaling problem into a rank $k$ update of a $d\times d$ matrix.

Comment: That is true, but I'm not quite sure how that helps. What I had in mind was using the fact that
$$
(I + BDB^T)^{-1} = ([I + BB^T] + B(D - I)B^T)^{-1}
$$

Comment: I see, interesting.